# ios 6 and ios 7 Gui issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

i have take 4 xib in which two xib for ios7 and another for ios6.i didn't use autolayout and my app is run fine on ios 7 both 3.5 and 4 inch,But the issue is occured when i run app in ios6.i differentiate the code as per as there ios verion.

when application start its navigation bar is going at some bottom side and if i aclick on another tab and again going back two my first tab navigation bar is on its perfect side.i took navigation bar  statically.

here is my code for one view controller when tabitem is clicked

```
NSLog(@"Iphone %f ",\[\[UIScreen mainScreen\] bounds\].size.height);

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        //The version of the device is iOS7.0 or higher.
        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            _HomeViewController_obj = \[\[_HomeViewController alloc\] initWithNibName:@"4HomeViewController" bundle:nil\];
        } else {
            _HomeViewController_obj            = \[\[_HomeViewController alloc\] initWithNibName:@"4HomeViewController_iphone4" bundle:nil\];
        }
        //call controller with ios7 xib here
    }
    else
    {
        //The version of the device is lower then iOS7.0.
        if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
            _HomeViewController_obj = \[\[_HomeViewController alloc\] initWithNibName:@"4HomeViewController_iphone5" bundle:nil\];
        } else {
            _HomeViewController_obj            = \[\[_HomeViewController alloc\] initWithNibName:@"4HomeViewController_iphoneOld" bundle:nil\];
        }

        //call controller with ios6 xib here
    }

     if(\[UIDevice currentDevice\].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
                NSLog(@"Ipad ");
            }
            else
            {

                NSLog(@"Iphone %f ",\[\[UIScreen mainScreen\] bounds\].size.height);
                if (\[\[UIScreen mainScreen\] bounds\].size.height == 568) {

                        \[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 525, 30, 40)\];
                        \[btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 525, 30, 40)\];
                        \[btn3 setFrame:CGRectMake(140, 525, 30, 40)\];
                        \[btn4 setFrame:CGRectMake(205, 522, 45, 45)\];
                        \[btn5 setFrame:CGRectMake(275, 525, 30, 40)\];

                               } else {


                    \[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)\];
                    \[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 436,40, 40)\];
                    \[btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(76, 436,40, 40)\];
                    \[btn3 setFrame:CGRectMake(140, 436,40, 40)\];
                    \[btn4 setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 436,40, 40)\];
                    \[btn5 setFrame:CGRectMake(260, 436,40, 40)\];
                    // this is iphone 4 xib
                }
            }![enter image description here][3]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why yourself messed up the code for multiple device screen

Comment: i didn't use autolayout and storyboard thats why i m facing this problem

Comment: put up your screen shot

Comment: @iDev i put screenshot please see.

Comment: don't edit answer post for posting question images

Comment: it's status bar issue

Comment: ok i put ur code in appdelegate and in xib set status bar None again there is an issue that navigation bar is overlapped by status bar in simulator can u please mail ur email id on rahulanand9776@gmail.com so i can send u my code

Comment: raja.integrass@gmail.com

Comment: @iDev u are offline sir

Answer (score 0):

it's status bar. add this code in your appdelegate/viewcontroller where you have modified the status height

```
 if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {

    self.window=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window];

     self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,-20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height+20);
    }
```